# Looping through and hiding some elements with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to hide elements based on a choice made in a pulldown. The way it should work is that if you click the pulldown and choose 1, the first paragraph with the class "date"  and the corresponding domains in the div with class "domains" should remain and the second (and the ones eventually coming after) should be hidden. It also needs to be reversible, if the user chooses another number in the pulldown.

It's basically a function allowing users to (in this case) display and hide domains based on number of days back in time.

Appreciate any help.

```
<select id="search3">
    <option value="">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>

<div class="dates">
    <p class="date">30.09.2015</p>
</div>

<div class="domains">
    <p class="30.09.2015">blabla.biz</p>
    <p class="30.09.2015">peeeek.com</p>
    <p class="30.09.2015">juppppp.net</p>
</div>

<div class="dates">
    <p class="date">29.09.2015</p>
</div>

<div class="domains">
    <p class="29.09.2015">okhvor.org</p>
    <p class="29.09.2015">jahahaha.tv</p>
</div>
```

Tried something I know is wrong, but :-)

```
if ($('#search3')!=0)
{
    tc=0;
    $('.date').each(function() {
        if (tc < s3data && $(".domains p").hasClass( $('.date').value ))
        {
            return true;
        }
        ++tc;
    });
```

Comment: What is your approach so far with **JQuery** Post it here.

Comment: Hmm....difficult to post alot of code in a comment. Will edit my first post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added few classes and used jquery hide() and show()

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/c_psumit/qbqvc5yd/1/)

JQuery Code

```
$('.dates').hide();
$('.domains').hide();
$('#search3').change(function(){
    $('.dates').hide();
    $('.domains').hide();
    val = $('#search3').val();
    i=0;
    while(i<=val) {
        $('.'+i).show();
        i++;
    }       
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but when you choose 2, both should be displayed and when you choose 1, only the first. Later on there will be 20 or so dates.

Comment: Cool! Looks promising :-) Sick kid here but will get back in 1-2 hours to check it out. Thanks alot!